# How do i connect from main window to next window in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

im beginner in Pyqt4.So, i need a help. I had do a multiple widget in Pyqt designer, so i want to connect my main window to my widget. In my main menu, there's a **enter** button and i want when i clicked the **enter** button, it will go to page2.ui Here is my code

MainWindow.py

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MainWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(707, 563)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(707, 563))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(707, 563))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Documents/Icon/2.0/TheBat.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label_start = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 731, 501))
        self.label_start.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_start.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Downloads/Workout routine program.jpg")))
        self.label_start.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_start"))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 500, 721, 51))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.enter = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Corbel"))
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.enter.setFont(font)
        self.enter.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Documents/Icon/2.0/install.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.enter.setIcon(icon1)
        self.enter.setCheckable(False)
        self.enter.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.enter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("enter"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.enter)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome to Workout Routine Program", None))
        self.enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

page2.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'page2_choosegender.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_page2(object):
    def setupUi(self, page2):
        page2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("page2"))
        page2.setEnabled(True)
        page2.resize(627, 459)
        self.label_male = QtGui.QLabel(page2)
        self.label_male.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 100, 251, 251))
        self.label_male.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_male.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Downloads/1455198182_Tony_Stark.png")))
        self.label_male.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_male"))
        self.label_female = QtGui.QLabel(page2)
        self.label_female.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 100, 251, 251))
        self.label_female.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_female.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Downloads/1455198167_Customer_Female_Dark.png")))
        self.label_female.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_female"))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(page2)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 360, 531, 80))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.pushButton_male = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Documents/Icon/2.0/Male.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_male.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_male.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_male"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_male)
        self.pushButton_female = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Documents/Icon/2.0/Female.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_female.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton_female.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton_female"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_female)
        self.textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit(page2)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 20, 531, 61))
        self.textEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("textEdit"))

        self.retranslateUi(page2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(page2)

    def retranslateUi(self, page2):
        page2.setWindowTitle(_translate("page2", "Choose your gender", None))
        self.pushButton_male.setText(_translate("page2", "Male", None))
        self.pushButton_female.setText(_translate("page2", "Female", None))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("page2", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;\">Are you ?</span></p></body></html>", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    page2 = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_page2()
    ui.setupUi(page2)
    page2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I hope you guys can help me . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wouldn't recommend you to continue the way you're going even the error message at the top warns you that changes in the auto-generate file would be lost if you regenerate it again. you should seperate your Ui file and your main code

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'MainWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from page2 import Ui_page2


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(707, 563)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(707, 563))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(707, 563))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Documents/Icon/2.0/TheBat.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.label_start = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 731, 501))
        self.label_start.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label_start.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Downloads/Workout routine program.jpg")))
        self.label_start.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_start"))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 500, 721, 51))
        self.horizontalLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayoutWidget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))

        # initialize the qwidget as an attribute of the class and set a listener on the button
        self.page2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        ui = Ui_page2()
        ui.setupUi(self.page2)

        self.enter = QtGui.QPushButton(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
        self.enter.clicked.connect(self.page2.show)

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Corbel"))
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.enter.setFont(font)
        self.enter.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../../Documents/Icon/2.0/install.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.enter.setIcon(icon1)
        self.enter.setCheckable(False)
        self.enter.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.enter.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("enter"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.enter)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Welcome to Workout Routine Program", None))
        self.enter.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter", None))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

as i said earlier your code is not structured properly, if it was it would be as easy as calling `self.hide()`,  `or self.close` but your `Ui_MainWindow` is not a `QWidget` or `QMainWindow` so it dosen't have that method the `QMainWindow` is constructed outside the class so you don't have access to it. with some hacking around it can be fixed but it's not good practice. i'll suggest you look at the git repo https://github.com/shuge/Qt-Python-Binding-Examples  and see how to organize your code. ideally the auto-generated ui file should be seperated from your logic...This makes it easier to modify your logic in future without messing up the ui or losing your changes when you generate the ui again

ideally you should inherit from QtGui.QMainWindow or some sort of widget

Your autogenerated ui file

ui.py

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(995, 717)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow)
        pass
```

logic.py

```
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
class MyUi(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(criticalPath, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

main.py

```
import sys
from logic import MyUi

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    #create a new object
    my_interface = MyUi()
    my_interface.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for reply, but how to make MainWindow automatically close after page2 have open ?